# Requirements.txt greater than equal to and then less than?

Tags: python, django, requirements.txt

I have this line in my requirements file

```
django>=1.10,<1.11
```

Does that mean I need to have Django version `>= 1.10` and then less than `1.11`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Yes**. The [pip manual <sup>[doc]</sup>](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/) has a section on the format of "*requirement specifiers*". These are documented in [PEP-508 <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/) and [PEP-440 <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-specifiers):

> The comparison operator determines the kind of version clause:
>
> 1. `~=`: Compatible release clause
> 2. `==`: Version matching clause
> 3. `!=`: Version exclusion clause
> 4. `<=`, `>=`: Inclusive ordered comparison clause
> 5. `<`, `>`: Exclusive ordered comparison clause
> 6. `===`: Arbitrary equality clause.
>
> The **comma (`","`) is equivalent to a logical and** operator: a candidate version must **match all given version clauses** in order to match the specifier as a whole.

So in your case it means that the Django version is `1.10` or higher and not `1.11` or higher (so `1.10` is fine, `1.10.1`, as well, but not `1.11`, `1.11.1`, or `2.0.1`).

Comment: Is there any way to say "any version except for this range"? In other words, how would I say [`setuptools` version `<45.0.0` *or* `>=49.9.1`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1963)>

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: not as far as I know nu, especially since there is no disjunction (logical or). You can do this with `!= 45.*, != 46.*, !=47.*, !=48.*, !=49.1.*, !=49.1.*, !=49.2.*, !=49.3.*, !=49.4.*, !=49.5.*, !=49.6.*, !=49.7.*, !=49.8.*, !=49.9.0.*`

Comment: I came to the same unfortunate conclusion. Luckily, I made a typo and the range is `49.1.1` (not `49.9.1`). So I used this: `setuptools !=45.*, !=46.*, !=47.*, !=48.*, !=49.1.0`. Thanks!